# Python: Getting a TypeError when trying to use the contents of a file that I've opened

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm new to python or programming in general really, and I've had this issue for the last couple of hours and I'm apparently god awful at figuring out what's going wrong.

```
def read_file(input_filename):
    file_list = []
    with open(input_filename, 'r') as open_file:
        for x in range(len(open_file)):
            print(open_file[x] +  " [" + str(x) + "]")
            if (x % 2) == 0:
                thisTuple = (open_file[x], open_file[x + 1])
                file_list.append(thisTuple)
```

I wish I could give something in return for any help more than gratitude, but it really would mean a lot if someone could give me any pointers on what I might be doing wrong here.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to read the file line-by-line or byte-by-byte?

Comment: @Carcigenicate oh yeah I forgot to add that.. sorry.
"TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()" is the typeerror that I'm getting.

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback to the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting an error is because of this statement:

`for x in range(len(open_file)):`

`open_file` does not implement the `__len__` Python magic function.  It is also not a subscriptable object (like a string).  It is a `TextIOWrapper`.  If you want to get the data as a string then you need to call `open_file.read()`:

```
data= open_file.read()
for x in range(len(data)):
    print(data[x] +  " [" + str(x) + "]")
    if (x % 2) == 0:
        thisTuple = (data[x], data[x + 1])
        file_list.append(thisTuple)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it was something with the "open_file" but I didn't understand what to use instead. It makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ...
for line in open_file:
    x = line.strip()
    # ...
```